# Apply Iteration on the each element in the vector with a time delay

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, time, iteration

I have a vector having 8 elements , i want each element ot be itertated from initial state "30.9" and after every 1 second it is changed from 0 to 10 and soo on till 100 step by step , after it reach 100 then iteration moves to the second element 
"30.9" makes it 0 and then increase 10 value per second reaches highes to 100 and then back to initial condition.

```
hb =  [30.9, 30.9, 33.9, 41.6, 46.6, 54.4, 59.2, 65.6]
counter = 1
multiplier = 1
for i in range(1,9):
  Application.Variables['P():///Constant'+str(i)+'/Value'].ValueConverted = hb[counter]
  multiplier = multiplier + 1
  counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt using the time module and a nested for loop.
The [time module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) allows you to use time.sleep(), which will wait for a specified number of seconds. I also changed the range from 1,11, since that will allow for 10 iterations, as range iterates from the starting element to the end element-1.

```
import time
hb =  [30.9, 30.9, 33.9, 41.6, 46.6, 54.4, 59.2, 65.6]
counter = 1
multiplier = 1
for element in hb:
    print("Currently processing element: ", element)
    #Reset counter and multiplier after each loop
    counter = 1
    multiplier =1
    for i in range(1,11):
        #Do processing here
        multiplier = multiplier + 1
        counter = counter + 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Here is a screenshot of the program in progress:
[image]

Comment: But the requiremenrt is element starts from 0 till 100 in 10 steps and come back to ints initial poisition. then the second elecment same iteration applied.

Comment: What would the counter and multiplier be after one loop - do they retain the value after the first loop? What do you mean that it starts from 0 till 100 in 10 steps - do you want counter/multiplier to increment by 10 in each step so it reaches 100? If you have a sample output after one loop I can understand better.

Comment: your solution worked perfect thank you , how can i improve your rating ?

Comment: Glad I could help! Since you are new you cannot upvote yet so accepting the answer is the only thing - which you already did.

Comment: Thank you can you rate it ?